# Auto-populate Django Model field

Tags: python, django

I'm a little lost.

I want to auto-populate a Model field with data from another Model, according to the value of another field in the same model.

I have 2 models:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    value = models.DecimalField()

class Order(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, to_field="name", related_name='+')
    value = models.ForeignKey(Status, to_field="value", related_name='+')
```

When creating an `Order` the user will select the order's status (pending, complete, etc.) and the value of the order should auto-populate accordingly.  Maybe I'm tired, but I can't work this out. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

My thinking behind this structure is that each status has a specific monetary value, ie. Completed is £20, Abandoned is £5, Pending is 0.  So, an order starts off as pending, then later will either be marked complete or abandoned and generate the related value.  The value is tied to the status, and should update automatically according to the order status.

Comment: This structure doesn't make much sense. Why would `value` be in a Status model? Why do you want to store exactly the same content in two fields?

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 2 fields in Order. In Order model you need this:

```
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name='+')
```

And you can access name and value by `order.status.name` and `order.status.value`.

Answer (score 0):

For particular case you don't need two models. You can do it by single model using `choice` field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices

```
class Status(models.Model):

STATUS_PENDING = 0
STATUS_COMPLETE = 1
STATUS = (
    (STATUS_PENDING, 'Pending'),
    (STATUS_COMPLETE, 'Complete'),
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0.0))
status = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=STATUS)
```

Comment: The `name` field in the `Status` model IS the `status`.  The `status` is tied to the order and indicates the status of the order.  The possible options being in the `Status` model.  I did originally use `choices` but decided against them so as not to hardcode status options into the models.

Comment: why to let user write the status when you can fix it by choice, and why add extra model to make your query slow to access the field by adding joins..